# globals dict error

Tags: python, global

When I try to run this code

```
"""Hello World"""

print globals()[__doc__]
```

Why do I get this error ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\myProjects\python\Python-13.py", line 3, in <module>
print globals()[__doc__]
KeyError: 'Hello World'
```

Context : I just want the doc string of current module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `print globals()['__doc__']`.

Answer (score 5):

The docstring of the current module is `__doc__`. In your code you are trying to use that string as key in the global dictionary of the module.

To be clear, to print the docstring, just do `print __doc__`.

Comment: Because what you are doing is essentially `globals()['Hello World']`. Since your module does not contain the name `Hello World`, this fails.